# Minimum of a potential with $SO(2)\times SO(2)$ symmetry

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, symmetry-breaking

Given

$
\Phi=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\phi_1\\
\phi_2\\
\phi_3\\
\phi_4
\end{array}\right)
$

where $\Phi$ is real, I have the following Lagrangian density:

$
\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \Phi)^T\partial^\mu \Phi -\frac{1}{2} \Phi^T M^2 \Phi-\frac{\lambda}{2m^2}(\Phi^TM^2 \Phi)^2
$

where

$
M^2 =m^2\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & -1& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0& -1
\end{array}\right)
$

I think that the fields have a symmetry $SO(2)\times SO(2)$, since I can rotate indipendently the first two fields or the second two fields. However then I expect a symmetry breaking only for the second two fields because they have the minus sign on the mass term. Is it this correct? Is there an easy way to find the minima of the potential?

Comment: I think the symmetry should be O(2,2), that is, the one that leaves $M^2$ invariant ($SO(2)xSO(2)$ is a subgroup of O(2,2)), right ?

Comment: I think you're right but I am not so an expert in group theory so any hint or clarification is welcomed

Comment: I don't think I can help much more, unfortunately. What I meant is that if you find a minimum, say for $\Phi=(0,0,0,\phi)$, then you can find another minimum using an O(2,2) transformation, which is defined as the group of matrix $U$ such that $U M^2 U^T=M^2$. However, this group is not compact, and I don't know much about field theories in that case...

Comment: If I were you, I would start with a simpler example, using a smaller group, such as O(1,1), that is, with two fields and $M^2=diag(1,-1)$.

Comment: @Adam 's last point might help you. In this 2-field theory you see "symmetry breaking" in the potential, with one massive and one massless field, even though O(1,1) is not a symmetry of the kinetic term... It is a "custodial" symmetry of the potential *only*, so the tree level goldston will develop a mass in pert theory! In your original example, O(2,2) is only custodial, so only *one* of the 3 massless states you will find will be a true goldston (the one coming from the lower block) and the two upper massless fields will develop a mass radiatively (common mass, as their SO(2) is intact.)

Comment: @CosmasZachos: I'm not familiar with this custodial symmetry, though I think I understand your point (I had indeed missed the fact that the kinetic term is only O(2)xO(2) symmetric, and I can definitely imagine that fluctuations will dynamically generate a mass to the other terms). However, do you have a reference for the case of non-compact symmetry group in QFTs ?

Comment: @Adam : sorry, not knowledgeable enough... [Bars-Gunaydin](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103940471) might be a good starting point...  The custodial symmetry of the Higgs potential in the standard model is SO(4) and there is a *huge*, messy, noisy, ugly, literature on *that*. But finite dim reps of noncompacts are non unitary, so...

Comment: @Adam apologies, you are not interested in supergroups... scrap the above... but that's where [these guys live](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157381901575)... look at p345 ... the nonunitarity is dealt with through nonlinear (spont.broken) realizations and creative stunts....

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks for the references. I am in fact interested in supergroups, so that a whole nother story.

Answer (score 0):

You need to minimise

$$\left(\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2-\phi_3^2-\phi_4^2\right)+\lambda\left(\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2-\phi_3^2-\phi_4^2\right)^2$$

By differentiation with respect to any of the $\phi_i^2$:

$$1 + 2\lambda \left(\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2-\phi_3^2-\phi_4^2\right) = 0$$

So there is a set of degenerate extrema, whose equation is

$$\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2-\phi_3^2-\phi_4^2 = -\frac{1}{2\lambda}$$

The matrix of second-order derivatives is diagonal, and its diagonal is

$$2\lambda\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

from which you can read where the extrema are actually minima.